# Android Editable ListView (preference / dialog)

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog, android-preferences

I need a editable list view with strings where items can be renamed added and removed.

That should be - if possible in a preference view / dialog.

What is the best way to implement that?
Are there libs? - I didn't find any.

My current solution is a multilined EditText dialog with one entry each line.

Comment: Use Listview, each list view item will contain edit text, delete icon, edit icon[optional]. by default edittext will not be editable, whenever user clicks on row edittext should be enabled & soft keyboard board.alternate clicks on list view item will enable/disable edit text

Comment: is it possible in a dialog or preference? that's the more important part for me (but thank you for your suggestion)

Comment: Add listview to your dialog